# How to create a ListView with GridView inside

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, gridview

I am trying to put ListView items in my ListView, which is seperated into columns with a GridView object.

I have no idea how to put new items in the columns, and there are not so many useful tutorials on the web.

Here's the XAML code for the ListView:

```
        <ListView Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="68" Height="138" Name="listView1" Width="444">
        </ListView>
```

And the GridView is created dynamically:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridView grdView = new GridView();

        GridViewColumn nameColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        nameColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Time");
        nameColumn.Header = "Time";
        nameColumn.Width = 120;
        grdView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

        GridViewColumn ageColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        ageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
        ageColumn.Header = "Date";
        ageColumn.Width = 120;
        grdView.Columns.Add(ageColumn);

        listView1.View = grdView;
    }
```

I want to add some Items into the ListView, how to do that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001012/creating-the-listview-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it to some data

[ItemsControl.ItemsSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)